# Is there any good reason not to merge the tags [pixi] and [pixi.js]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I wasn't sure where to go with this, but since there is no "report" button for tags and you need a certain amount of rep to merge tags, this is pretty much the only place I could think of.

I think the tags [pixi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi) and [pixi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixi.js) should be merged and pixi.js should be kept, as it is the official name of the library.